# Can I mimic doctrine's lazy load on postLoad

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony-2.8, doctrine-odm

I have an entity `User` which has a OneToMany relation with an entity named  `Session`.
So far so good, I can do `$myUser->getSessions()` and get an array with all the sessions related to the `$myUser`.

`Session` also had a OneToMany relation with another entity `Moment`.

Now, this `Moment` Entity has moved into a Document because that part of the app is now on a MongoDB database mainly for performance issues.

To keep the application running without rewriting lot of code I've created a Doctrine Listener like this :

```
class DoctrineListenerPostLoad
{
    private $container;
    private $dm;

    public function __construct(Container $container, DocumentManager $dm)
    {
        $this->dm           = $dm;
        $this->container    = $container;
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if($entity instanceof Session) 
        {
            $entity->setMoments(array());
            $entity     = $args->getEntity();
            $moments    = $this->dm->getRepository('AppBundle\Document\Moment')->findBy(array('idSession' => $entity->getId()));
            $entity->setMoments($moments);  
        }   
    }
}
```

So when an instance of `Session` is loaded the listener get the moments related to the session in the mongodb database.
But by doing so I lose doctrine's lazy load. And when I need to get all the Sessions of an user (but not the Moments) I get a `OutOfMemoryException` due to the high amount of data because it does load the moments.

I know I can just "unbind" `Session` and `Moment` and do a `DocRepo->findBy(array('idSession' => $entity->getId())` when I need it, but I will have to rewrite a lot of nicely working code on the app. 
Is there another way ? Like maybe loading the DocumentManager in the entity (Yeks!) or check if a getter has been called in the `PostLoad` ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Use [Ocramius/ProxyManager](https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager) to wrap database call and defer until somebody tries to use the proxied collection (should be quite straightforward)

2: Manually craft ODM's `PersistentCollection` that is uninitialized. If you pretend to use `@ReferenceMany(repositoryMethod="getBySession", targetDocument=Moment::class)` for the `moments`, all should work fine as collection will be lazy-loaded again using a repository method you write (the method will be given `Session` object as a first argument). Roughly your `postLoad` will look like:

```
$mapping = [
    'association' => \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadata::REFERENCE_MANY,
    'repositoryMethod' => 'getBySession',
    'strategy' => 'setArray',
    'targetDocument' => Moment::class,
];
$coll = $this->dm->getConfiguration()->getPersistentCollectionFactory()->create($this->dm, $mapping);
$coll->setOwner($entity, $mapping);
$coll->setInitialized(false);
$entity->setMoments($coll);
```

Please note that I might have missed some required `$mapping` attribute and this approach may not work forever (it shouldn't break in 1.x though). If you don't want to "cheat" with reference mapping you might get away with mapping `Session` as a Document and mapping moments directly with `@ReferenceMany(repositoryMethod="getBySession", targetDocument=Moment::class)`, but I'm not sure about side-effects.

Comment: Thank you ! It looks promising, i'll give it a try on monday.